# PHP & Mysql, Checking if columns in a table matches another column in another table (Complicated)

Tags: php, mysql

I have managed to do what I wanted, but if the user does not match the first number then it says they have not matched any when they could have matched 5 etc... Think of it like a lottery :)

```
<?
include "includes/db_connect.php";

$email=$_SESSION["real_name"];
$sql="SELECT * from users WHERE email='$email'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // Start looping table row 

$one2=$rows['1'];
$two2=$rows['2'];
$three2=$rows['3'];
$four2=$rows['4'];
$five2=$rows['5'];
$six2=$rows['6'];
{
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$one2' OR `2` = '$one2' OR `3` = '$one2' OR `4` = '$one2' OR `5` = '$one2' OR `6` = '$one2' LIMIT 1");
        $get = mysql_num_rows($q);
if($get == 0) {
   echo 'Sorry you didnt match anything';
} else {
    $q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$two2' OR `2` = '$two2' OR `3` = '$two2' OR `4` = '$two2' OR `5` = '$two2' OR `6` = '$two2' LIMIT 1");
        $get1 = mysql_num_rows($q1);
if($get1 == 0) {
   echo 'You matched one number';
} else {
    $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$three2' OR `2` = '$three2' OR `3` = '$three2' OR `4` = '$three2' OR `5` = '$three2' OR `6` = '$three2' LIMIT 1");
        $get2 = mysql_num_rows($q2);
if($get2 == 0) {
   echo 'You matched two numbers';
} else {
   $q3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$four2' OR `2` = '$four2' OR `3` = '$four2' OR `4` = '$four2' OR `5` = '$four2' OR `6` = '$four2' LIMIT 1");
        $get3 = mysql_num_rows($q3);
if($get3 == 0) {
   echo 'You matched three numbers';
} else {
   $q4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$five2' OR `2` = '$five2' OR `3` = '$five2' OR `4` = '$five2' OR `5` = '$five2' OR `6` = '$five2' LIMIT 1");
        $get4 = mysql_num_rows($q4);
if($get4 == 0) {
   echo 'You matched four numbers';
} else {
    $q5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$six2' OR `2` = '$six2' OR `3` = '$six2' OR `4` = '$six2' OR `5` = '$six2' OR `6` = '$six2' LIMIT 1");
        $get5 = mysql_num_rows($q5);
if($get5 == 0) {
   echo 'You matched five numbers';
} else {
    echo 'You matched all the numbers';
} 
 ?>


<? }}}}}}} ?>
```

Now you have seen the code, I think i need explain it abit more.
one2-six2 are 6 numbers a user has chosen.
They need to be matched with the numbers in the table "numbers"
It works but if the user does not match their first number (one2) but match (two2) for example,  then it says they haven't matched any.

Any advice?

Comment: 1. Stop using MySQL_* its decrepit and use mysqli_* 2. End after every else before another if. Then for every sorry replace with sorry you didn't get your first/second/etc number then it will move on to the next to say you got number /two/three/ etc if got a correct number

Comment: 1. Stop using MySQL_* its decrepit and use mysqli_* 2. End after every else before another if. Then for every sorry replace with sorry you didn't get your first/second/etc number then it will move on to the next to say you got number /two/three/ etc if got a correct number.  Should go like if($one2 === $one2_query ) { $correct = $number + 1; } else { $wrong = $number_wrong +1;} //end of statenents Echo 'you got '.$number.' Numbers Right and '.$number_wrong.' Number wrong.';

Comment: Could you post an example like:
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$one2' OR `2` = '$one2' OR `3` = '$one2' OR `4` = '$one2' OR `5` = '$one2' OR `6` = '$one2' LIMIT 1");
        $get = mysql_num_rows($q);
if($get == 0) {
   echo 'Sorry you didnt match anything';
} else {
/// First Number matches, checks second etc..

My code works how i want it to work but if their first number doesnt match but second does it says none works so where it says on the first one no matches, it needs check their second one etc... 

I am quite new to PHP hence im confused

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
include "includes/db_connect.php";

$email=$_SESSION["real_name"];
$sql="SELECT * from users WHERE email='$email'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$number = 0;
$number_wrong = 0;

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // Start looping table row 

$one2=$rows['1'];
$two2=$rows['2'];
$three2=$rows['3'];
$four2=$rows['4'];
$five2=$rows['5'];
$six2=$rows['6'];
{
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$one2' OR `2` = '$one2' OR `3` = '$one2' OR `4` = '$one2' OR `5` = '$one2' OR `6` = '$one2' LIMIT 1");
        $get = mysql_num_rows($q);
if($get == 0) {
   $number++;
} else {

$number_wrong++;
}
    $q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$two2' OR `2` = '$two2' OR `3` = '$two2' OR `4` = '$two2' OR `5` = '$two2' OR `6` = '$two2' LIMIT 1");
        $get1 = mysql_num_rows($q1);
if($get1 == 0) {
   $number++;
} else {

$number_wrong++;
}

    $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$three2' OR `2` = '$three2' OR `3` = '$three2' OR `4` = '$three2' OR `5` = '$three2' OR `6` = '$three2' LIMIT 1");
        $get2 = mysql_num_rows($q2);
if($get2 == 0) {
    $number++;
} else {

$number_wrong++;
}
   $q3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$four2' OR `2` = '$four2' OR `3` = '$four2' OR `4` = '$four2' OR `5` = '$four2' OR `6` = '$four2' LIMIT 1");
        $get3 = mysql_num_rows($q3);
if($get3 == 0) {
   $number++;
} else {

$number_wrong++;
}
   $q4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$five2' OR `2` = '$five2' OR `3` = '$five2' OR `4` = '$five2' OR `5` = '$five2' OR `6` = '$five2' LIMIT 1");
        $get4 = mysql_num_rows($q4);
if($get4 == 0) {
$number++;
} else {

$number_wrong++;
}
    $q5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `1` = '$six2' OR `2` = '$six2' OR `3` = '$six2' OR `4` = '$six2' OR `5` = '$six2' OR `6` = '$six2' LIMIT 1");
        $get5 = mysql_num_rows($q5);
if($get5 == 0) {
    $number++;
} else {

$number_wrong++;
}}

Echo 'you got '.$number.' Numbers right and '.$number_wrong.' Numbers wrong.';
 ?>
```

Sorry was doing this on my phone. Not the easiest. Please check syntax.

Comment: That looks good,
It says "you got Numbers right and Numbers wrong." 
Doesnt save the amount of numbers
Any ideas

Comment: After a few adjustments,
Its 100% working how i wanted it.

Comment: Ahh brilliant. What did you change?

Comment: Just the end echo, I only wanted to display how many they got right :) Its all working fine now so cheers

Comment: yeah, marked it as answered so it doesn't appear on the opened questions list